# Display the value of form input

Tags: php, html

I have a form with a input field like this:

```
<input type="hidden" id="name" name="name" value="">
```

Value of this input is changing trough some javascript function.

Now i would like to displays this value dynamicaly. For example:

```
<h1>This is the name: *input name value here*</h1>\
```

I know that you can use the value from different elements on a form when submiting, using the $_POST["name"]. But what about getting the value on same page dynamicaly.

Comment: Simply write JS code with eventHandler. And you won't need use PHP if this value doesn't need to be saved or transferred somewhere else.

Comment: You can do as @AksenPhas pointed out or  you can also use jQuery and bind an event handler to the element and update your target element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name" value="" onblur="myFunction()">
<h1 id="fname"> </h1>
<script>
function myFunction() {
  document.getElementById("fname").innerHTML = document.getElementById("name").value;
}
</script>
```